Do Americans think the Durham investigation (into the Clinton camp) was politically motivated?
We had some Qs here about the public opinion of investigations into Trump's camp, and we learned from those that Republicans think these investigations (and trials) were/are overwhelmingly politically motivated.
Given that the Durham investigation resulted only in acquittals in the Clinton camp, with the exception of one FBI lawyer who was convicted (whom didn't work for Clinton though), what is the US public opinion of this Durham investigation, overall, do they think it was politically motivated?

To be more clear, I'm asking about polls on this. I'm aware some Democrats in Congress have already voiced their low opinion about Durham's investigation (this was well-hinted in Wikipedia), e.g.:

“Mr. Durham constructed a flimsy story built on shaky inferences and dog whistles to far-right conspiracy theorists,” [Rep. D-N.Y.] Jerry Nadler said on Wednesday. “By prolonging his investigation, Durham was able to keep Donald Trump’s talking points in the news, long after Trump left office.”
Rep. Adam Schiff (D-Calif.) also noted that Durham’s report did not dispute any of the findings in special counsel Robert Mueller’s 2019 report on Trump’s links to Russia, which was initiated by the FBI probe. “The only distinguishment between [Mueller’s] investigation and yours is he refused to bring charges where he couldn’t prove guilt beyond a reasonable doubt,” Schiff told Durham, “And you did.”

Etc. So, I'm asking about polls, even if after reading the above snippets one might guess how polls could look like on this issue.

Somewhat related, Trump has filed a civil lawsuit against Clinton and many others on [roughly] same grounds--charging conspiracy, which also has a civil law version. It didn't go to well in the court of first instance, but now it seems stuck in "monster appeal" in the 11th Cir.

But I'm asking strictly about Durham's investigation here, conducted by the state. The opinion about Trump's own [civil] lawsuit against Clinton is somewhat of a different matter.

You're looking for opinion polls asking if the decision to hold an investigation was overall politically motivated, or if its conclusions or the specific investigation into the Clintons were politically motivated? I can't find any relevant polls but it might be buried in the regular polling reports produced by big organizations.

@StuartF: Polls. Opinions from one person or another I already found in the Wikipedia page, which even has a section titled "Motivated by right-wing conspiracy theory".

I have no idea if poll data exists about that investigation specifically but you could certainly look at whether general opinion of the FBI changed.
